# Automatically Add Git Version with PHPDoc

Tags: php, git, phpdoc

I was wondering if anyone might know of a way to insert the Git version for a file / repository to a comment block so PHP Doc can automatically reflect it when generating documentation?

Comment: PHPDoc stopped being developed before Git became popular so I doubt you can do that.  I'd look into switching to a more modern doc generator if I were you, such as DocBlox or ApiGen.

Answer (score 1):

phpDocumentor is not what puts that info into the docs... it would have to appear in your docblock already.

It sounds like you're used to having $Id$ tags in your docblocks, that get populated automatically by CVS and SVN when you check out the code... aka "Keyword Expansion".

Git does allow for that -- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a phing script which will find the latest version of your project. And replace a token with the version in each file/selected files.

For example (I have used SVN in example)
in you phing script

to get latest svn version

```
<svnlastrevision workingcopy="${path.to.project.dir}" propertyname="svn.lastrevision" />
```

In your files where you want to svn version, put a token with name `@svn.lastrevision@`

following code will replace this token with version number

```
<!-- Apply the version change to all files. -->
        <reflexive>
            <fileset dir="${dir.to.change.version}">
                 <include name="**/*.*" />
            </fileset>
             <filterchain>
                <replacetokens>
                    <token key="svn.lastrevision" value="${svn.lastrevision}" />
                </replacetokens>
            </filterchain>
        </reflexive>
```